# php, html, javascript ajax spewing code to browser

Tags: php, javascript, html, ajax

So yesterday I decided to learn php, Javascript and html. I wrote a php script that gives the correct output when I run it with php5 in the terminal but when I try to add it to a webpage using Javascript it prints bits and pieces of the last ~1/4 of code along with the table I was trying to print but without the variable values. It does this even if I remove all instances of echo from the script.

Here's the php:

```
<?php
$foo = $_GET["t"];

$con = mysql_connect('host', 'user', 'pw');
if (!$con)
{
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$db_selected = mysql_select_db('db', $con);
if (!$db_selected)
{
    die('Can\'t use db: ' . mysql_error());
}

$sql = sprintf("SELECT fun FROM table WHERE op = '%s'", $foo);

$data = mysql_query($sql);
$result = array();
$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($data)){
    $result[$i] = $row[0];
    $i++;
}

$dist = $name = range(min($result), max($result), .5);

for($i=0; $i<count($dist); $i++)
{
$temp = array_fill(0,count($result),0);
    for($j=0; $j<count($result); $j++)
    {
    if ($result[$j] < $dist[$i]) $temp[$j] = 1;
    }
$dist[$i] = array_sum($temp)/count($temp);
}

$temp = array_fill(0,count($dist),0);

for($i=0; $i<count($dist); $i++)
{
if ($dist[$i] < 0.5) $temp[$i] = 1;
}

$best = $name[array_sum($temp)-1];
$less = 0;
$more = 0;

$temp = array_fill(0, count($result), 0);
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++)
{
if ($result[$i] < $best) $temp[$i] = 1;
}

$less = array_sum($temp)/count($temp);

$temp = array_fill(0, count($result), 0);
for($i=0; $i<count($result); $i++)
{
if ($result[$i] > $best) $temp[$i] = 1;
}

$more = array_sum($temp)/count($temp);

$equal = 1 - $less - $more;

echo "<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Best</th>
<th>Less</th>
<th>Equal</th>
<th>More</th>
</tr>";

echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>  $best  </td>";
echo "<td>  $less </td>";
echo "<td>  $equal  </td>";
echo "<td>  $more  </td>";
echo "</tr>";
echo "</table>";

mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and the output I get.

$best) $temp[$i] = 1; } $more = array_sum($temp)/count($temp); $equal = 1 - $less - $more; echo " Best Less Equal More "; echo ""; echo " $best "; echo " $less "; echo " $equal "; echo " $more "; echo ""; echo ""; mysql_close($con); ?>

output when i run php5 with arbitrary input value in terminal is:

```
<table border='1'>
<tr>
<th>Best</th>
<th>Less</th>
<th>Equal</th>
<th>More</th>
</tr><tr><td>  27  </td><td>  0.48417721518987 </td><td>  0.048523206751055  </td><td>  0.46729957805907  </td></tr></table>
```

which is what i want.

heres the html/javascript if that helps.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function hreCalc(str)
{
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  } 
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","funCalc.php?t="+str,true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form>
<select name="totals" onchange="hreCalc(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a total:</option>
<option value="5.5">5.5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="6.5">6.5</option>
<option value="8.5">8.5</option>
</select>
</form>
<br></br>
<div id="txtHint"><b>Total info will be listed here.</b></div>

</body>
</html>
```

i just started learning these languages and ive tried everything i can think of. the problem seems to be coming from the > signs but I cant figure out how to fix it and as far as i can tell you should be able to use > in php without it causing problems with html. im using ubuntu 12.04 so may be i dont have everything installed that i need?

Comment: because javascript is client side, and php is server side, you can't output php with js, but you can output js with php

Comment: What output do you get if you run "funCalc.php" directly in the browser without calling it from an XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: well first off: SQL injection. My website was a victim of it. I learned my lesson: keep backups and sanitize input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is you use alert() to display the entire response - or just access the page directly in the browser - you'll see that it's actually returning the entire php file; it's just that your browser is interpreting everything up to that point as one long HTML tag.

This is almost certainly caused by your server not being set to serve .php files with the application/x- httpd-php mime type, instructions for doing which will depend on your server.

**edit** That's assuming that you actually have a web server set up, rather than directly accessing the files on your hard drive. If not then that'll be your problem and you need to go and install Apache or IIS.

Comment: thanks. i figured it out. i was using tomcat but didnt have php set up correctly. thanks to everyone that helped. sorry for wasting your time with a stupid ?

Comment: @user1519291 No worries; I remember getting stuck on a similar issue when I was getting started with PHP. If my answer helped you with this could you mark it as your accepted answer, please? Thanks :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing everything right, since the PHP command line works fine.

Here is a possible answer:

"the PHP code after the great-than operator (>) is at risk of being corrupted by the HTML editor's text formatting algorithms.

PHP code with greater-than symbols can be safely embedded into HTML by surrounding it with a pair of HTML-style comment delimiters + fake HTML end & start stags, as PHP-style comments.

Example:

```
<html>
<body>
Safe-<?php
/*><!--*/
    if (4>3) {
        echo "PHP-";
    }
/*--><?*/
?>embedding
</body>
</html>"
```

So, in short, you make your code less readable, but by adding in fake html comment tags, you should be able to trick your interpreter into doing the right thing.

Found here (near the bottom of the page): http://php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phpmode.php

Comment: thanks. that seems to be the problem so ill read up on it. my first attempts to do this have suppressed all output

Comment: still havent been able to figure it out. found this: [http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=144158](http://forums.phpfreaks.com/index.php?topic=144158). but that shouldnt be the issue since my file is a .php. whenever i add fake html comment tags there is no output at all even though it still works in console.

Comment: It's not worth destroying the readability of your code like this; if this does turn out to be the issue (which to be honest, I'm dubious of) just switch to a less terrible HTML editor.